# Can you make some sort of structure out of transcendental numbers?

Tags: abstract-algebra, transcendental-numbers

Let $T$ be the set of trancendental numbers over $\Bbb{Q}$.   Then it is an easy proof that for all $a,b \in T$, either $a + b$ or $ab$ or both are transcendental.  What if you defined the operation $*$ on $T$ to be $+$ where appropriate and $\cdot$ where appropriate.  And if both are appropriate prefer $+$.  Then $T$ is closed under $*$.   Further $a*b = b*a$ since we're in a field.  $a*b*c$ could underneath be $a+b c$, so this structure is non-associative.  Is there a better way to build an algebraic structure from them?

Comment: what algebraic structure would you gain? It should be a magma if I am correct which nearly doesn't have any algebraic structure

Comment: Furthermore if you assume the axiom of choice any non empty set can be turned into a group